# XML content does not seem to be XML using read text: '/var/folders/_v/4fhshkb92kq_bnyv7dkxmh9c0000gn/T//Rtmp17F8m5/tmp.CBPLpCrO9L/word/document.xml'

Tags: r

I am currently working on a project in R where I collected a number of online news stories and saved them as pdfs in word. Then I attempted to upload the data into R and ran in to problems. The code I used is below:

```
setwd("/Users/dk/Dropbox/Corpus")
getwd()
directory<-"/Users/dk/Dropbox/Corpus/nsle"
directory
library(quanteda)
library(readtext)

mydocs<- readtext(directory, encoding = "UTF-8", docvarsfrom = "filenames")`
```

the error I am recieving is as follows:

> Error: XML content does not seem to be XML:
>   '/var/folders/_v/4fhshkb92kq_bnyv7dkxmh9c0000gn/T//Rtmp17F8m5/tmp.CBPLpCrO9L/word/document.xml

In addition: Warning message:
In utils::unzip(i, exdir = td) : error 1 in extracting from zip file

I am only asking the question on this website because all of the other askers were using XML or R-curl.
When I mess with the directory- based on other answers- I receive this:

> Error in get(method, envir = home) :    lazy-load database
>   '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/XML/R/XML.rdb'
>   is corrupt In addition: Warning messages:
>
> 1: In getSource(x,
>   text_field = text_field, encoding = encoding, ...) :   Unsupported
>   extension " r " of file /Users/dinaklimkina/Dropbox/Corpus/New Sample
>   Legislature/New Project 08_03_18.R treating as plain text
>
> 2: In utils::unzip(i, exdir = td) : error 1 in extracting from zip
>   file
>
> 3: In .registerS3method(fin[i, 1], fin[i, 2], fin[i, 3], fin[i, 4],  :
>   restarting interrupted promise evaluation
>
> 4: In get(method, envir = home) :   restarting interrupted promise
>   evaluation
>
> 5: In get(method, envir = home) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1

Should I be using a different package?
Thanks so much!
D